# JS - How to repetativly fire a function at random time for certain period

Tags: javascript, random, settimeout

I would like to imitate progress bar getting random lengh added 0% to 100% with series of messages displayed in certain sequence but also in random time.

In order to do that I'm staring two independent loops using JS setTimeout method with a random number genearted inside of each loop. But each loop not supposed to be longer than 30 seconds and with the way I'm doing I can't control that.

For the second loop I have to fire the function for 11 times randomly but fit that into 30 seconds as well.

The progress bar moves by changing its width. The messages supposed to be right above that. It looks like this:

HTML:

```
<span id="progressMsg"></span>
<input type="hidden" id="progressMsgNumber">
<div class="pogress progress-info slim" id="progressBar" style="width=1%"></div>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(progressBar, 1000);
setTimeout(progressMsn, 1000);

function progressBar() {
    barWidth = document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width.slice(0, -1); //to get number without "%" char
    if (barWidth >=100) {
        // We are done
    } else {
        minRand = 1;
        maxRand = 5;
        randSeconds = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand;
        barWidth = Number(barWidth)+randSeconds;
        document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = barWidth+"%";
        setTimeout(progressBar, randSeconds*1000);
    }

}

function progressMsg() {
    msgList = new array ("Msg1", "Msg2", ... "Msg11");
    barWidth = document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width.slice(0, -1);
    if (barWidth >=100) {
        // We are done
    } else {
        msgNumber = document.getElementById("progressMsgNumber").val;
        msgNumber++;
        document.getElementById("progressMsg").innerHTML = msgList[msgNumber];
        document.getElementById("progressMsgNumber").val = msgNumber;
        minRand = 1;
        maxRand = 5;
        randSeconds = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand;
        setTimeout(progressMsg, randSeconds*1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: what you need to do is split 30 seconds into a series of numbers, randomly - if you know how many messages there are, then it is easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to create ALL the random times beforehand, then you can manipulate the times in such a way as to guarantee exact 30 seconds total time.

Note: code below, for demo purposes, has times 1/10th of what you would use, i.e. you'd want

```
        minRand = 1000,
        maxRand = 5000,
        maxTime = 30000;
```

```js
function progressMsg() {       
    const msgList = ["Msg1", "Msg2", "Msg3", "Msg4", "Msg5", "Msg6", "Msg7", "Msg8", "Msg9", "Msg10", "Msg11"],
        minRand = 100,
        maxRand = 500,
        maxTime = 3000;
    let triggers = Array.from({length:11}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand);
    triggers.forEach((n, i, a) => a[i] = (a[i-1]||0) + a[i]);
    const mult = maxTime / triggers.slice(-1);
    triggers = triggers.map(v => Math.floor(Math.ceil(v * mult)));
    
    const update = (t, i) => {
        console.log(t, Math.round(t/maxTime * 100) + '%', msgList[i]);
    }
    triggers.forEach((n, i) => setTimeout(update, n, n, i));
}
progressMsg();
```

to make it work with your code

```
function progressMsg() {       
    const msgList = ["Msg1", "Msg2", "Msg3", "Msg4", "Msg5", "Msg6", "Msg7", "Msg8", "Msg9", "Msg10", "Msg11"],
        minRand = 1000,
        maxRand = 5000,
        maxTime = 30000;
    // create an array of random times, e.g. 1,3,4,2,1...
    let triggers = Array.from({length:11}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand);
    // accumulate times, so we'd have e.g. 1,4,8,10,11...
    triggers.forEach((n, i, a) => a[i] = (a[i-1]||0) + a[i]);
    const mult = maxTime / triggers.slice(-1);
    // adjust so the last time is exactly maxTime
    triggers = triggers.map(v => Math.floor(Math.ceil(v * mult)));

    const update = i => {
        document.getElementById("progressMsg").innerHTML = msgList[i];
        document.getElementById("progressMsgNumber").val = i;
    }
    // start all the timeouts at once, because we have cumulative times
    triggers.forEach((n, i) => setTimeout(update, n, i));
}

function progressBar() {
    const minRand = 1000,
        maxRand = 5000,
        maxTime = 30000,
        bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    let time = 0;
    let triggers = [];
    // here we just keep adding random times until we reach maxTime
    while (time < maxTime) {
        triggers.push(time += Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand);
    }
    const mult = maxTime / triggers.slice(-1);
    // adjust times so last time is exactly maxTime
    triggers = triggers.map(v => Math.floor(Math.ceil(v * mult)));

    const update = t => {
        bar.style.width = (100*t/maxTime) + '%';
    }
    triggers.forEach(n => setTimeout(update, n, n));
}
```

---

In answer to comment - one way to know when all is done is using promises

```
const delay = (fn, delay, ...params) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(fn, delay, ...params));

function progressMsg() {       
    const msgList = ["Msg1", "Msg2", "Msg3", "Msg4", "Msg5", "Msg6", "Msg7", "Msg8", "Msg9", "Msg10", "Msg11"],
        minRand = 1000,
        maxRand = 5000,
        maxTime = 30000;
    // create an array of random times, e.g. 1,3,4,2,1...
    let triggers = Array.from({length:11}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand);
    // accumulate times, so we'd have e.g. 1,4,8,10,11...
    triggers.forEach((n, i, a) => a[i] = (a[i-1]||0) + a[i]);
    const mult = maxTime / triggers.slice(-1);
    // adjust so the last time is exactly maxTime
    triggers = triggers.map(v => Math.floor(Math.ceil(v * mult)));

    const update = i => {
        document.getElementById("progressMsg").innerHTML = msgList[i];
        document.getElementById("progressMsgNumber").val = i;
    }
    // start all the timeouts at once, because we have cumulative times
    return Promise.all(triggers.map((n, i) => delay(update, n, i)));
}

function progressBar() {
    const minRand = 1000,
        maxRand = 5000,
        maxTime = 30000,
        bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    let time = 0;
    let triggers = [];
    // here we just keep adding random times until we reach maxTime
    while (time < maxTime) {
        triggers.push(time += Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand + 1)) + minRand);
    }
    const mult = maxTime / triggers.slice(-1);
    // adjust times so last time is exactly maxTime
    triggers = triggers.map(v => Math.floor(Math.ceil(v * mult)));

    const update = t => {
        bar.style.width = (100*t/maxTime) + '%';
    }
    return Promise.all(triggers.map(n => delay(update, n, n)));
}

// usage

Promise.all([progressMsg(), progressBar()]).then(() => {
    // all done here
});
```

Comment: I completelly admire your solution and thank you for explanations, creating all the random times beforehand is the way to go

Comment: Sorry, is there any callBack or some kind of indication I could you to find out that both loops are completed?

Comment: I experience compatibility problems on old browsers with `let`

Comment: Transpile it ... Babel

Answer (score 1):

you can store the full spent time and number of displayed messages in variables

```
let spentTime = 0; // Declare 
let displayedMessages = 0; 
function progressMsg() {
    ....
        setTimeout(() => { // Edit 
          progressMsg();
          spentTime += randSecods; // add the seconds of this tick
          displayedMessages++;
        }, randSeconds*1000);
    }

}
```

you can then use it to change the min and max in any tick passed on the spent time and the left messages 
something like

```
maxSeconds = (fullTime - spentTime) / (numOfMessages - displayedMessages)
```

will make sure all the messages are displayed, you can change the min value too, to seem more naturally.

Comment: what if the random seconds you get are 4,5,4,5,4,5,3 - so after only 7 of the 11 messages, you've already reached 30 seconds?

Comment: @JaromandaX the idea is to limit the max random seconds to prevent that actually usibg the spent time and number of messages left to be displayed. 
for example the code I suggested `maxSeconds = (fullTime - spentTime) / (numOfMessages - displayedMessages)` will set a max limit of 2.7 (30/11) at the first tick and if the randoms all was the max the sequence will be 
2.7, 2.7,2.7, ...,2.7

Comment: yeah, sure, but random numbers are random, so you could easily get to a situation where the interval for the last 4 or 5 messages is very small :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I think if it's a problem, then we're missing the point of random numbers, and actually the last line was an example using the spent time and left messages you can prevent even that by whatever logic you like.

Comment: I guess I can't see your logic very well :p

Comment: @JaromandaX 'cause there'is not any actually :p, The OP wanted to send the messages in 30 second separated by random seconds, so I thought that using the spent time  it's possible to do whatever they want to approach a satisfying result. 
the last line of code was an example of how they can mess with these values.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your functions into Promise, with one additional Promise to resolve itself in 30 seconds, and then use Promise.race 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: how can this help if OP requires second random loop to have all 11 messages displayed?